# How to change object.value == null?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, null

I have a some field of entity

```
public virtual Trailer TempTrailer { get; set; }
```

How to change this fields value to null? I used:

```
var temptrailer = model.TempTrailer != null ? 
    await trailerService.FindByIdAsync(model.TempTrailer.Id) : 
    null;

entity.TempTrailer = temptrailer == null ? null : temptrailer;`
```

but does not accept null values. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Is Trailer a struct or a class?

Comment: I assume that `Trailer` is a `struct`? Structs can't be `null`. So if you need to assign a `null` value, change the type from `struct` to `class` *or* change the declared type from `Trailer` to `Trailer?` or `Nullable<Trailer>`

Comment: Trailer is a class

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Not have error,code working is good,but value is not changed

Answer (score 1):

> `entity.TempTrailer = temptrailer == null ? null : temptrailer;`

So basically, you are want to assign `null`, if  `temptrailer` is `null`, otherwise `temptrailer`. You could also just write the following statement to achieve just the same:

```
entity.TempTrailer = temptrailer;
```

Nevertheless, if you want to assign a value using the conditional operator (`?:`), you can "cast" `null`:

```
entity.TempTrailer = temptrailer == null ? (Trailer)null : temptrailer;
```

Comment: Your code is not working.
In debug is work, in realese is not work
I don't know why

Comment: Are you saying that after that statement, `entity.TempTrailer` is not null, or are you saying that the corresponding column in the corresponding row in the database is not null? Please be explicit about what the problem is instead of just "isn't working".

Comment: Me need change value of TempTrailer in DB.
For example, Tractor have TempTrailer,
In DB,in table Tractor have TempTrailer_ID
Me need clear this TempTrailer_Id,that is clear this value

Comment: Are you working with Entity Framework? Are you saving your context?

Comment: Yeap,working with EF.
Save with await Context.SaveChangesAsync();